# Using Kotlin reflection how to determine which constructor parameters were given as `val`?

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, reflection, constructor

#### Simple case A (no problem here)

```kotlin
class A(val title: String)
```

For instance `a`, we will get the parameters list from `a.javaClass.kotlin.primaryConstructor!!.valueParameters`.

#### Simple case B (no problem here)

```kotlin
class B(titleRaw: String) {             // no val
  val titleFinal = titleRaw.uppercase() // the property has different name
}
```

We can determine that the `titleRaw` parameter does not create a property because there is no `titleRaw` property on the object.  We will use [valueParameters](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/value-parameters.html) and [memberProperties](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-properties.html) to detect that.

#### Difficult case:

```kotlin
class C(title: String) {        // no val
  val title = title.uppercase() // property with the same name
}
```

How to detect that the `title` property does not return the value of the `title` parameter?

#### A little background

Having an instance of a class, I want to know what constructor argument values it was instantiated with. If that's not possible (the primary constructor takes arguments that aren't properties), I'd like to throw an exception.

Comment: Seeing your background, wouldn't it be easier to just throw an exception if the class is not a data class? Data class primary constructors cannot have non-val/var parameters.

Comment: I am writing a fairly universal function, and I would not want to be limited to data classes. In fact, I wanted to roughly repeat the check from `kotlinx.serialization`. There, objects can be made serializable by marking them as `@Serializable`. But if the constructor has parameters that are not properties, applying `@Serializable` results in a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

`kotlinx.serialization` doesn't use reflection, it's a compiler plugin so they have full access to the source code / AST, where it's an easy check if the `val` is in the constructor (physically).

If you look at the decompiled versions of your example classes you can see that there's not much difference:
[image]

Those some bits in `d1` (data1) might be just what you need.
I tried to have a glance at the structures in the [metadata library](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/kotlinx-metadata/jvm/ReadMe.md), but nothing significant stood out as helpful.

Even if metadata is not helping, not all hope is lost, you can consider using a third party tool (which has access to AST) as the regulator. e.g. a simple Detekt rule might do the job. Or if you want to stick to first party Kotlin, a compiler plugin.